# SQL multipart identifier into GrOUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a left join like this:

```
LEFT MERGE JOIN --IVA0A
( SELECT VOUCHER,DATAAREAID,ISNULL(VENDTRANSID,0)AS LJT, SUM(IIF(TAXITEMGROUP = 'ANTICIPOS',-1*TAXBASEAMOUNT,TAXBASEAMOUNT))AS TAXBASEAMOUNT,
SUM(IIF(TAXITEMGROUP = 'ANTICIPOS',-1*TAXAMOUNT,TAXAMOUNT)) AS TAXAMOUNT FROM 
##CPP TT
WHERE (
         (TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0A' OR  TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0AFA' OR  TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0AEXP') OR 
         (TT.TAXITEMGROUP = 'ANTICIPOS' AND (TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0AP' OR  TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0AFAP' OR  TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IVA0AEXPP'))
      )
GROUP BY TT.VOUCHER,TT.DATAAREAID,ISNULL(LJT.VENDTRANSID,0)) 
AS TTIVA0A ON VT.VOUCHER = TTIVA0A.VOUCHER AND TTIVA0A.DATAAREAID = VT.DATAAREAID
and IIF(TTIVA0A.LJT=0,VT.RECID,TTIVA0A.LJT) = VT.RECID
```

Problem is when I trying to use `GROUP BY` clause

SQL returns:

> The multi-part identifier "LJT.VENDTRANSID" could not be bound.

I can't understand why it happen, can anyone explain me please? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you want to group by `ISNULL(VENDTRANSID,0) AS LJT`, since you can't use the alias `LJT` in the `WHERE` clause you should group using the expression itself:

```
GROUP BY TT.VOUCHER, TT.DATAAREAID, ISNULL(VENDTRANSID,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

LJT is the alias given to column ISNULL(VENTTRANSID, 0).

I think that, in GROUP BY clause instead of ISNULL(LJT.VENTTRANSID, 0) if you just give ISNULL(VENTTRANSID, 0) it will solve the issue.